# Save values to preference summary which needs to persists

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferences, preferenceactivity

I have preferences.xml which contains checkboxes, preferences..etc. I'm extending preference activity and setting preference layout with addpreferencesfromxml method.
Click on first preference opens TimePickerDialog, and user needs to pick hour and minute.
When user clicks "ok" i set summary of that certain preference to value that user picked (let's say 3:05 AM ).

I want to save this value, so when user leaves my preference activity, and if returns back the value (and summary) persists (its not default value, but instead it should be value the user choose previously).

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the values when you open the PreferenceActivity (see [Reading Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs)).

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#CustomSave

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    // When the user selects "OK", persist the new value
    if (positiveResult) {
        persistInt(mNewValue);
    }
}
```